# Adding a link to "New Document Set"

Tags: ribbon, document

I want to make it easier for the end-users to create a new document set. Right now they have to access the ribbon buttons through various clicks.

Is it possible to make a direct link to the "New Document Set" form, which can be used on any other page?

The link I get when I right-click on the form is to AllItems.aspx and not the actual form the end-users have to fill out.

Comment: Would you be happy to have your users click the "New Document" button on the AllItems.aspx page to create a new document set, except just changed the "New Document" text to "New Project", or whatever it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just opened the new document set form by going to `ribbon > files > new document  > new document set`, copied the url and created a quick launch link with the same url. It works fine for me.

Steps :

- Go to `ribbon > files > new document  > new document set` in the given list
- Copy the whole URL
- In the right, at the bottom of the quick launch - Click, EDIT LINK (this is assuming you have default SP2013 settings)
- Click on the `+ Link`
- Put the url in the Address field, put a name
- Click on OK and then click Save

You can create new document sets for a given list this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to override display template [using JSLink](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) . Target url u can find in SPD in appropriate content type settings. For me this url is _layouts/15/NewDocSet.aspx. I guess u have the same. 
In addition calling this page u have to pass different params like List={list id}&Source={all items link}&ContentTypeId={content type id}&RootFolder={folder name}

Answer (score 0):

I have used a page for end users to create a document set without having to fill out the new form.  Sometimes the create form can become cumbersome and is not the easiest to customize.  For that reason I prefer to have end users create the new document set, then give them a link to a default edit form that I can customize to what they need to see.

**.txt file**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add .js file path here -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.DocumentManagement.js"></script>

<style>
#setCreationContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
#submitSet {
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:25px;
}
</style>

<div id="setCreationContainer">
    <h1>Create New Document Set</h1>
    <h2>Enter set name below and click the button to create it.</h2><br/>
    <div id="centerContainer">
        <b>Title:</b> <input type="text" id="taskTitle"></input><br><br>
        <button type="button" id="submitSet">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**.js file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitSet").click(function(){           
        var title = $("#taskTitle").val();      
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.documentmanagement.js', 'SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet', function() {
           createDocumentSet(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents',title,printInfo,logError);

           function printInfo()
           {
              console.log('Doc Set has been created'); 
              alert("The document set has been created successfully."); 
           }

           function logError(sender,args)
           { 
              console.log(args.get_message());
              alert("The document set was NOT added");
           }

        });                                     
    });
}); 

function createDocumentSet(siteUrl,listTitle,docSetName,success,error) {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    ctx.load(list);

    var parentFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
    ctx.load(parentFolder);

    var docSetContentTypeID = "0x0120D520";
    var docSetContentType = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
    ctx.load(docSetContentType);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function (){ 
        SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(ctx, parentFolder, docSetName, docSetContentType.get_id());
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
    }, 
    error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a solution that worked for me here [Add a ‘Create New Document Set’ link to a web-page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51892/add-a-create-new-document-set-link-to-a-web-page)

> I've tried a mixture of things and came across the following solution. I tried a solution to copy the URL for creating a new document set, but the link always led to a 'something went wrong' page.
>
> The solution is based on https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/launch-document-content-type-templates-from-any-web-page-with-a-link/
>
> General steps after the doc set content type is created:
>
> - Modify the Doc Set view to "Show toolbar"
> - Search the page source for 'Create a new x' where x = name of document set item. For example "Create a new document set". Find the one located under the 'ms-toolbar' class and examine the block.
> - Copy the (long) code after onMenuClick, looks like `"javascript:NewItem2(event, &#39;\u002fsites\yoursite\u002fsubsite\..."` and ends with a content type ID
> - (Optional) Decode the `\u002f` with `/` and the `&#39;` with `'`
> - Create a CEWP / script editor webpart with hyperlink using the 'onclick' event `<a onclick="javascript:NewItem2(event, '/sites/yoursite/yoursubsite/...">Create new document set</a>`
> - Set the view toolbar to 'no toolbar'
> - (Optional) Change advanced settings on list to 'open in dialog'
>
> Haven't sorted out how to edit the new docset aspx, but this was good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new page with a Script Editor web part and redirect to the New Document Set URL. Then add your link to the new page. As the URL to create a new Document Set is usually longer than 255 characters you can't add it as a link on a Promoted Links web part.

Script Editor Web Part contents

```
<script>
window.location.replace("https://your sp URL/DocLib/_layouts/15/NewDocSet.aspx?List=8e35b6fb%2Da15d%2D42d8%2Dba55%2D1a19118a2f51&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fsp%2FDocLib%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x0120D520008573907D05F28946AC7CB51D667D668100CFB8D54BDE0252428252AACD1FFBF1F1&RootFolder=%2FDocLib");
</script>
```

You'd need to update the URL to your URL to create a new Doc Set. Then you have to click apply quickly and as you do, you'll then be redirected to the new document set form.

Alternatively, You could just add it as a link on a page.